# Serving images based on where people are viewing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, geolocation

I would like to serve different background images based on a) where people are coming from (USA, UK, Australia) and b) whether it is day or night.

Is it possible doing this using only frontend technologies (I have complete access to the html, not to the actual app's backend though?).

Comment: You can do this with either JavaScript's location API (which requires the user's permission) or using PHP by checking the IP Address against a database of country-based IPs. PHP would be easier

Comment: Thank you @Armaan, I do - as pointed out - not have access to the actual processing. So the JS will have to do. Any good link as where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the local time of the client to determine wether it is day or night

and have a look here,  there is a javascript example of how to get your location.

http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation